# Trim value in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Does anyone have any ideas on how to trim `default_code` in the search command? I need to remove trailing spaces.

```
product_id = self.search([('default_code','=',fs_product['id'])], limit=1)
```

Comment: use `<str>.strip()` function or specifically trailing spaces use `lstrip()`

Comment: how do you use the .strip() command on default_code?

Comment: In the left side, you can only use a field name of the current model, or a relationship traversal through a `Many2one` using dot-notation e.g. `street` or `partner_id.country`. Instead of trying to trim the default code, check the comparison operator `like`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

`product_id = self.search([('default_code','ilike',fs_product['id'])], limit=1)`